# URL generation removes port

Tags: php, laravel

I was trying to send an email when I encountered this error. So what I did is I created an event and on it's listeners I want to send an email that will validate it's email address. Just to be sure that everything will be secure I tried using URL::signedRoute to create a URL wherein if the user would click on it, it will go to the address produced by URL::signedRoute. What I just notice is that on the url that it created, there was no port in it.

Heres my mailable class

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

class AccountValidation extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $user,$link;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->link = URL::temporarySignedRoute(
            'activateaccount', now()->addHour(), ['email'=>$user->email,'answer'=>'1']
        );
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from('welly@wellington.com')->view('emails.accountvalidation');
    }
}
```

The address from web.php

```
Route::get('/activate/{email}/{answer}','MyController@activateaccount')->name('activateaccount')->middleware('signed');
```

Here's the URL that it produced.

```
http://localhost/activate/ewan@yahoo.com/1?expires=1526801279&amp;signature=823cfaece0a5184db2ef7e79e3f4bc9e3b4cbf362b98884323b0fe2605886912
```

I want the URL to have port 8000 like `http://localhost:8000`. Thank you for helping and excuse my grammar.

Comment: check your `.env`, your `app_url` probably doesn't have the port defined

Comment: Ohhhh thank you very much Ohgodwhy. It's working now :)